# How to add date in sqlite database android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have to two date variables in my bean class

```
public class bean {
    private Date dos;
    private Date doe;
}
```

In my DAO class

```
// columns in my sqlite database table
public class TaskDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String  C_DOS = "d1";
    public static final String  C_DOE = "d2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("CREATE TABLE "+TBNAME);
        sb.append(" ("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
        sb.append(C_DOS+" INTEGER,");
        sb.append(C_DOE+" INTEGER)");

        String sql = sb.toString();
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    void addbean(bean b)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(C_DOS,b.getdos);
        values.put(C_DOE,b.getdoe);

        database.insert(TBNAME,null,values);
    }
```

the ContentValues put is giving an error of incompatible types. 
How do I fix this such that I can extract the later to use it in other DAO CRUD functions?

Comment: Dates in SQLite are normally **strings**. These are the valid [TimeStrings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: @BobMalooga the values.put is giving an incompatible type error.

Comment: **Of course**. You defined the fields as INTEGER. Now you can't pass them a STRING.

Comment: If you mean in the stringbuilder where I create the table, I changed it to String, no difference. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long` as type.

So you can store `mDate.getTime()` in you database and get the correct time with `new Date(millies)`

```
public boolean addBean(Bean bean) {

    long result;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, bean.getId());
    values.put(C_DOS, formatDateToLong(bean.getDos()));
    values.put(C_DOE, formatDateToLong(bean.getDoe()));

    result = db.insert(TBNAME, null, values);
    db.close();

    return result > 0;
}
```

Therefor you can use helper functions.

```
public static Date formatLongToDate(Long date){
     return new Date(date);
}

public static Long formatDateToLong(Date date){
    return date.getTime();
}
```

If you use a database it is better to use an id in your model:

```
public class Bean {
    private Long id;
    private Date dos;
    private Date doe;
}
```

To get your data from the database try:

```
 public Bean getBean(Long id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TBNAME, new String[] { ID, C_DOS, C_DOE}, ID + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);

    Bean mBean = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        new mBean (
            cursor.getLong(0),
            DateHelper.formatLongToDate(cursor.getLong(1)),
            DateHelper.formatLongToDate(cursor.getLong(2))
        );
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return mBean ;
}
```

Comment: public static final String  C_DOS = "Date_Start";  ---> This is my date column in my beanDAO, if I change the datatype to long then what do I name the column, which I will need access to in the other functions such delete or sort.

Comment: You will handle it with the id. You need do change your `onCreate(){...}`. There is a good tutorial on http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Try to use this tutorial to start and code your database in general. Then    use `Long` to store your Date as explained in the helper functions.

Comment: By the way `C_DOS` is just the name of the database column, it has to be unique. So  `public static final String C_DOS = "Date_Start";  
public static final String C_DOE = "Date_End";  
public static final String ID = "Bean_Id";`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_data";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String uid, String email, String name, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }
}
```

after that you can insert data like this ....

```
SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(this);
db.addUser(_uni_id,_email,_username,_reg_date);
```

and you can also get data like this ...

```
SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    String name = user.get("username_key");
```

for drop all (you can edit the class SQLiteHandler to drop specific row)...

```
db.deleteUsers();
```

I hope its useful for you

Comment: Thank you. But my problem is that I have a Date variable that I want to store in my Sqlite table.

Comment: @PoojaKarki in your code the problem was you user String variable with Integer data type in Table ... if you want use String variable in the Table you have use varchar(100) ... 100 is size

Comment: Your code dont answer the problem. He asked to handle datatype `Date` and not to handle SQLLite as a database in general.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the following code :

```
values.put(C_DOS,b.getdos);
values.put(C_DOE,b.getdoe);
```

Is it

```
values.put(C_DOS,b.getdos());
values.put(C_DOE,b.getdoe());
```

that you're trying to do?

If you want to store time as an integer, then modify the above two lines to :

```
values.put(C_DOS,b.getdos().getTime());
values.put(C_DOE,b.getdoe().getTime());
```

I'm assuming `getdos` and `getdoe` are defined in your `bean` class and have a return type `Date`.

Can you please edit your question to include the error message you're being shown?
The type of values added to the `ContentValues` using `put` are not checked at compile time and so, the incompatible type error may have been caused by something else and not because of the `Date` type.